# Passing fscanf to struct

Tags: c

I'm trying to open a file and pass to `struct`, I'm using `fscanf()` with a loop, but it only saves one the `struct` the last read:

Imagine a file:

```
JR John Rambo 24353432 
JL John Lennon 6435463
```

I'm using this code:

```
typedef struct people{
    char code[10];
    char name[100];
    long telephone;
}PEOPLE;

int read(PEOPLE people[], int n_p){
    char temp;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("example.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    while(!feof(fp)){
        fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %d\n", people[n_p].code,people[n_p].name,
               &people[n_p].telephone);
    }
}
```

The Problem is that he only saves the last line of the file...Should I do a if cicle??

Another question is how can I separate a similar file but with ";"

Comment: n_p doesn't change, maybe you forgot to increment it?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you are scanning for 3 strings (`%s`) and one int (`%d`) when you pass only 3 parameters in your `fscanf()`. You could add a `char first_name[50];` in your `struct` and then do:

```
fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %d\n", people[n_p].code,people[n_p].first_name,
         people[n_p].name, &people[n_p].telephone);
```

You always `fscanf()` the file until you have nothing more to read (due to the `!feof(fp)` because of the while. So in the last `people[n_p]` variable the last line of the file will be saved.

You could remove the `while` from `read()` and also add the `FILE *` as a parameter to the function so that you don't open the file each time you call `read()`.

Something like this maybe:

```
main()
{
   FILE* fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");
   int i = 0;

   while (!feof(fp)) {
       read(people, i, fp);
       i++;
   }
}

int read(PEOPLE people[], int n_p, FILE* fp){
   char temp;

   if(fp==NULL){
       printf("Error\n");
       return -1;
   }
   fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %d\n", people[n_p].code,people[n_p].first_name, 
         people[n_p].name, &people[n_p].telephone);

}
```

For using the `;` as a separator you can change `fscanf()` to this:

```
 fscanf(fp, "%[^;]; %[^;]; %d\n", people[n_p].code,people[n_p].name,
             &people[n_p].telephone);
```

**EDIT** I wrote the above code which can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/EQqPiteC) and it works fine with this [example.txt file](http://pastebin.com/ug2BMgu6) as input.

Comment: If i don't loop with the while he only saves the first...Thanks

Comment: @P3druh77 As you see I loop inside the `main()` function. Did you do that? Also what' the n_p size? Could you show us the rest of your code?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're not changing the n_p variable.  You need some sort of variable to keep track of which index of the people[] array you're updating.

Additionally, hopefully you've got a large enough people array to hold all the entries in the file.

Comment: i know the problem is the index, but i already try to do if, but is the same;

Comment: @P3druh77:  Which tells us nothing.  If thedaian's suggestions don't help, you need to tell us what you tried and what happened.

Comment: @P3druh77 What I'm saying is you need to do something with n_p.  equality's answer has some code that should help.